# Phpstorm Fails To Deploy/Upload Files Auto Generated By The JS & CSS YUI Compressor

Tags: javascript, css, phpstorm, file-watcher

I use PhpStorm 10.0.3 (the latest currently). Ever since version 8.0 I have added two YUI **File Watchers** under **Settings** > **Tools**

YUI Compressor JS and YUI COmpressor CSS

The file watcher settings are as recommended in any place I have read. For instance, the JS Compressor settings are as shown in the image below:

[image: PhpStorm YUI JS File watcher settings]

And the CSS Compressor settings...

[image: PhpStorm YUI CSS File watcher settings]

The compressors themselves work as expected for all projects that I create. However, some projects seem not to detect the new files auto generated by these compressors, in my case ***.min.js*** and **.min.css** respectively. Every setting for these two file watchers seems identical from project to project. Specifically, after YUI has run and duly compressed the files accordingly, on some projects only the uncompressed file is detected as having changed and consequently included in the deployment automatic upload (on explicit save). The compressed files are not uploaded at all. I am forced to have to select the specific file(s) and upload manually. Of course it's frustrating and tedious.

The file deployment options are as below...

[image: phpstorm file deployment options]

What is wrong??? Why can't I upload the autogenerated files automatically, even after I repeat <kbd>CTR</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> after the compression is complete???

Comment: If you alt+tab away from PhpStorm and then back - does it upload the files?

Comment: Please enable "Upload external changes" option as well -- files produced by file watcher (external task basically) are treated as external.

Comment: @obe ALT-TAB or any form of leaving the window (and I use multiple monitors so it's easy) doesn't have any effect on the filewatchers except the initial compressor activity when there are changes to a file. CRTL+S doesn't still upload any autogenerated files.

Comment: @LazyOne that is what I needed to do. It has worked. Bless you!

Answer (score 1):

Please enable `Upload external changes` option as well in your Deployment Options (last screenshot).

Files produced by file watcher (external task basically) are treated as external changes (as they are not modified by you directly in editor but get "compiled/processed" from the "source" file).